# How to use AutoFixture to build with customized properties while keeping type customizations?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, autofixture

I am trying to use autofixture to create an object but there are certain properties that I want to always be defaulted (while the rest could be auto generated). However, whenever I setup an customization it gets overwritten when I build with customizations.

```
void Main()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<Person>(composer => composer.With(p => p.Name, "Ben"));

    var person = fixture.Build<Person>()
        .With(p => p.DateOfBirth, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
        .Create();

    /*  RESULT OF person below
    Name    null
    DateOfBirth 1/1/1900
    StreetAddress   StreetAddressafd6b86b-376a-4355-9a9c-fbae34731453
    State   State019e867b-ac5e-418f-805b-a64146bc06bc
    */
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set;}

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set;}

    public string StreetAddress { get; set;}

    public string State { get; set;}
}
```

The `Name` and `DateOfBirth` property customizations do not conflict so I don't know why Name ends up being null. I would expect name to be `Ben`.

How can I get it so both customizations are applied (ie. `Name = "Ben"` and `DateOfBirth = 1/1/1900`)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As @DavidOsborne correctly pointed out, the behavior you are seeing is [as designed](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Fixture.cs#L297-L300).

A [better approach](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/18/EncapsulatingAutoFixtureCustomizations/) is to organize your customizations in separate classes and then enable them as needed by a specific test scenario.

A customization object implements the `ICustomization` interface and its job is to configure the `Fixture` object in a specific way. Here's an example:

```
public class AllPersonsAreNamedBen : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Person>(composer =>
            composer.With(p => p.Name, "Ben"));
    }
}

public class AllPersonsAreBornIn1900 : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Person>(composer =>
            composer.With(p => p.DateOfBirth, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)));
    }
}
```

You can enable a customization on a specific `Fixture` by using the `Customize` method, for example:

```
fixture.Customize(new AllPersonsAreNamedBen());
```

or:

```
fixture.Customize(new AllPersonsAreBornIn1900());
```

You can also combine multiple customizations into a new one by using the `CompositeCustomization` class:

```
public class AllPersonsAreNamedBenAndAreBornIn1900 : CompositeCustomization
{
    public AllPersonsAreNamedBenAndAreBornIn1900()
        : base(new AllPersonsAreNamedBen(),
               new AllPersonsAreBornIn1900())
    {
    }
}
```

at which point you can simply say:

```
fixture.Customize(new AllPersonsAreNamedBenAndAreBornIn1900());
```

However, keep in mind that the order in which the customizations are applied on a `Fixture` matters: the last one wins and can potentially *override* the previous ones, as @MarkSeemann pointed out in the comments. This, too, is [by design](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheorderofAutoFixtureCustomizationsmatter).

So, while you *can* combine existing customizations that work on *different* types, in this particular case, since both customizations target the same type, you'll have to create a new customization to encapsulate all the settings for the `Person` type combined:

```
public class AllPersonsAreNamedBenAndAreBornIn1900 : CompositeCustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Person>(composer =>
            composer.With(p => p.Name, "Ben")
                    .With(p => p.DateOfBirth, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)));
    }
}
```

As a general rule, keeping your customizations small and *focused* enables you to [reuse them](http://megakemp.com/2013/04/16/general-purpose-customizations-with-autofixture/) in different tests, combining them for specific test scenarios.

Comment: Isn't `AllPersonsAreNamedBen` going to [override](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheorderofAutoFixtureCustomizationsmatter) `AllPersonsAreBornIn1900`?

Comment: I stand corrected. Since both customizations work on the same type, they absolutely will. Thanks for calling it out! This is one aspect of AutoFixture that bites me from time to time – I wish I could combine multiple customizations incrementally like that so *bad* that I sometimes forget it's not possible.

Comment: Downvoted because it is misleading - you cannot combine two customizations that customize one type. It would be nice to update this answer since it has the most upvotes.

Comment: @wirher I explictly wrote: "_So, while you can combine existing customizations that work on different types, in this particular case, since both customizations target the same type, you'll have to create a new customization to encapsulate all the settings for the Person type combined_". How is it misleading?

Answer (score 13):

This looks like it's by design:

> Note that the Build method chain is best understood as a one-off Customization. It bypasses all Customizations on the `Fixture` instance. Instead, it allows fine-grained control when building a specific specimen. However, in most cases, adding a convention-based `ICustomization` is a better, more flexible option.

...from the `Build()` method's documentation.

I appreciate that this is probably not an ideal answer. However, the documentation does provide a hint as to how you might arrive at one.