# AutoFixture: how to create property's value without prefix

Tags: c#, autofixture

For my test I need to have the Name property contains just a Guid's representaion without prefixed property's name. I've tried to solve with FromFactory method (see comment in the code) but had no success.

```c#
private class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}

[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    Fixture fixture = new();
    // var a = fixture.Build<A>().FromFactory(() => new() { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }).Create<A>();
    var a = fixture.Create<A>();
    a.Name.Should().NotStartWith("Name");
}
```

Comment: FromFactory isn't used for this purpose and doesn't work to this effect, see https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to customize:

```
fixture.Customize<A>(c => c.With(x => x.Name, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
```

Then, simply create:

```
var myMarvelousVariable = fixture.Create<A>();
```

Comment: Is it possible to disable prefixing with property names globally?

Comment: @mrt181, as I know you can't do it, but there are customization classes, you can write them on your own and reuse hhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688932/how-to-use-autofixture-to-build-with-customized-properties-while-keeping-type-cu