Unexpected behavior in Autofixture when customizing booleans
I understand that AutoFixture has a strategy how booleans are created (starting at boolean value true). At least there seams to be a pattern:
public class Foo
{
    public bool SomeBoolean { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void Verify_Autofixture_Boolean_Strategy()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    
    var model = fixture.Build<Foo>().CreateMany();
    
    model.Select(x => x.SomeBoolean)
        .Should()
        .BeEquivalentTo([true, false, true]);
}

What I do not understand, is why it ignores the customization that I explicitly made for an instance of IFixture.
[Fact]
public void Autofixture_Should_Allow_Boolean_Customizations()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    
    fixture.Customize<Foo>(
        composer =>
            composer.With(x => x.SomeBoolean, false)
    );

    var model = fixture.Build<Foo>().Create();
    // Is true, why?
    Assert.False(model.SomeBoolean);
}

Freezing a bool does not seem to be an option for me, since if you consider a more complex model (with potentially many booleans), if you want to make sure that all but one of them are randomized and you can control which one has an explicit value.

NOTE: When I omit the Build<T> invocation, i.e. execute var model = fixture.Create<Foo>(); it works, but I don't see why the Build<T> invocation should bring new sorts of problems.

I think I understand the root of the problem. The Build<T> method resets the current customizations in the Fixture and gives you a clean start

Something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38694180/1162077
